# transform:translate not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to use this code to center a div horizontally. It works fine in everything except safari (on windows and mac!) When I checked [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) it says its fine for beyond version 3.2 and I have 5.1.7.

I must be doing something wrong.

```
.heroimage {
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    }

.heroimage article {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100;
        left:50%;
        top:128px;
        transform:translate(-50%,0%);
       -webkit-transform:-webkit-translate(-50%,0%);
       -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
       -moz-transform:translate(-50%,0);
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#5b6370
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your browser prefixes are a little messed up.

```
.heroimage {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.heroimage article {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 50%;
    top: 128px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,0%);
            transform: translate(-50%,0%);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5b6370;
}
```